# Duplicate event when editingDidEnd called on UITextField RxSwift

Tags: rx-swift

I have a text field that is used to capture the users' login name.

1. The user taps inside of the text field.  The text field emits an empty string event.
2. The user then taps in some text ("123").  The text field emits an event for each character.
3. The user then taps inside of another text field.  The text field emits an event that represents the latest state of the text field ("123").

I'm wondering why the text field emits the last event, and is there a way to suppress the last event.  I tried adding `distinctUntilChanged` but that had no effect.  I would think that `distinctUntilChanged` would not fire the last event since it is the same as the previous event.

```
let userNameStream: Observable<String> = userNameText
  .rx
  .text
  .orEmpty
  .skip(1)
  .debug("userNameStream")
  .asObservable()
  .share(replay:1)
  .distinctUntilChanged()
```

The output

```
018-02-21 06:05:29.303: userNameStream -> Event next()
  userNameText : editingDidBegin
2018-02-21 06:05:38.448: userNameStream -> Event next(1)
2018-02-21 06:05:43.369: userNameStream -> Event next(12)
2018-02-21 06:05:48.880: userNameStream -> Event next(123)
2018-02-21 06:06:03.224: userNameStream -> Event next(123) // Duplicate Event!
  userNameText : editingDidEnd
```

Answer (score 0):

Move the `debug` operator after the `distinctUntilChanged` operator

```
let userNameStream: Observable<String> = userNameText
  .rx
  .text
  .orEmpty
  .skip(1)
  .distinctUntilChanged()
  .debug("userNameStream")
  .asObservable()
  .share(replay:1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using: **RxCocoa (4.1.2), RxSwift (4.1.2)**

Please try the following code:

```
let disposeBag = DisposeBag()
userNameText
        .rx
        .text
        .orEmpty
        .distinctUntilChanged()
        .debug()
        .subscribe()
        .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

Log

```
2018-02-22 11:47:21.618: ViewController.swift:26 (viewDidLoad()) -> subscribed
2018-02-22 11:47:21.620: ViewController.swift:26 (viewDidLoad()) -> Event next()
2018-02-22 11:47:29.560: ViewController.swift:26 (viewDidLoad()) -> Event next(a)
2018-02-22 11:47:30.046: ViewController.swift:26 (viewDidLoad()) -> Event next(ab)
2018-02-22 11:47:30.464: ViewController.swift:26 (viewDidLoad()) -> Event next(abc)
```

If you have problems please post your library version so I can help.